# REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered

Tags: com, registry

I have two applications built using VS19 and both are calling the same dll that calls CoCreateInstance to create an object of the class associated with an CLSID. The CLSID is registered.
One application works fine and the other is failing with the error REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered.
Everything is registered I have checked the registry.
The executables and dlls are all installed in the same folder.

Comment: Believe it or not but REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG means ... the COM object's class identifier is not registered. You may think it is, but it's not. Maybe be an x86 vs x64 registry issue or any other indirect issue. You can use a tool such as Procmon's sysinternals (filter by process name for example) to determine what keys are read, what keys are missing.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers to debug the issue. I used Process Explorer tool to find out  the problem with the registry entry for the specified CLSID. The problem was the Codebase entry that specifies the path for the C# assembly was missing in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by using /codebase option to register it. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase xxx.dll